# COMP2 to trigger One-Pulse mode on STM32L1

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, timer, comparator, stm32l

I am trying to use the output of COMP2 to trigger the One-Pulse mode of a timer (in my example TIM4, but it's quite flexible if it needs to change to another timer) on the STM32L1 series.

In the reference manual, the explanation for the One-Pulse mode uses TI2FP2 as the timer trigger, which is linked to the Input Capture on channel 2 of the timer, however the output of the comparator can only be redirected to Input Capture on channel 4 (except for TIM10 but it doesn't have a second channel to output the PWM on...), or to OCREF Clear.

I have tried redirecting the COMP2 output to:

- “OCxREF Clear” of TIM4,
- the Input Capture 4 of TIM4,
- the Input Capture 4 of TIM3 and using ITR2 as the TIM4 trigger (ITR2 is TIM3 when used on TIM4)

but none of those options worked.

Should any of these configurations have worked and I just didn’t set them up properly?

Am I supposed to do it differently?

Is there no way to connect the two directly and I should for example start the One-Pulse mode from the COMP2 interrupt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the timers' block diagram I couldn't find a direct method either, there are apparently no signals going from CH4 to the trigger unit.

If you'd like to avoid interrupts, and have a suitable free DMA channel, you can use that to start another timer. You can use `TIM2_CH4` or `TIM3_CH4` (I'm using TIM3 in the example), but there is no DMA channel for `TIM4_CH4`. You can stick to `TIM4` or use any other timer as the target.

- Set up `TIM4` for One-pulse mode, but do not start it yet. Figure out what value would go into `TIM4->CR1`, and store it in a memory variable, e.g. `volatile uint8_t tim4_cr1_start = TIM_CR1_OPM|TIM_CR1_CEN;` for the simplest case.
- Set up `DMA1_Channel3`, memory address is `&tim4_cr1_start` from above, peripheral address is `&TIM4->CR1`, transfer length is `1`. Use 8-bit mode, enable circular mode.
- Set `TIM3_CH4` to input capture, select polarity etc in `TIM3_CCER` and `TIM3_CCMR2`.
- Enable `CC4DE`, capture/compare 4 DMA request in `TIM3->DIER`.
- Start `TIM3`.
- Redirect COMP2 output to `TIM3_CH4` (you could use `TIM2_CH4' too, but there is no DMA channel for`TIM4_CH4`).

Now, a comparator event would trigger a capture on `TIM3_CH4`, which would instruct DMA to write a suitable value to `TIM4->CR1`. As the DMA is set to circular mode, it would copy the same value to `TIM4->CR1` on every subsequent capture event.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I haven't really used the DMA before, so it's definitely a good opportunity to learn how to use it! Do you know how this solution would compare to using interrupts in terms of delay between the COMP2 output changing and the One-Pulse mode starting on the output pin?

Comment: @BenoîtVernier Interrupt entry in a Cortex-M3 takes at least 12 cycles, then a [minimal handler implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/ONWuPL) would take at least another 5 cycles (1 for `MOVS`, 2 for `LDR` and 2 for `STR`). It's a theoretical minimum, I'd say 20-25 cycles are realistic. I don't really know about DMA latencies, I'd guess 3 or 4 cycles, and I'd be quite surprised if it would take more than 5. Then the timer needs maybe another 2 cycles to start in both cases.

Comment: @BenoîtVernier Actually an interrupt entry can be faster if another interrupt handler is finishing at the exact right moment ([see tail chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029201/tail-chaining-of-interrupts)). The point is, interrupt latency can be uncertain to +/- 6 cycles, DMA delay should be constant if you give this channel the highest priority level.